# Java "add return statement" error

Tags: java, return, unreachable-statement

```
public class1 foo ( class1 t)
{
    if ( object == null ) return t;
    else foo(t.childObject);
}
```

Java keeps telling me that there is no return statement. I can understand what is wrong here, but I cannot fix it without removing the recursion, which I really need. Is there any way to bypass this error?

Comment: What _reiteration_? You mean the recursion? Why would it break it?

Comment: Sorry , I meant recursion, you are right. Bad translation. I said I cannot fix it without breaking it, meaning I cannot find any solutions while keeping the recursion. What do you have in mind ?

Comment: How would you fix it _while breaking it_? Why would that break it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `return` in the else case.

```
public class1 foo ( class1 t)
{
    if ( object == null ) return t;
    else return foo(t.childObject);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the error appears to be gone. Let's hope this resolves my problem regarding its logical continuity.